# Relationship between distance in 3D space and its z depth

Tags: math, 3d, coordinates

I have a flat plane of 2D graphics with a camera pointing at them. I want to get the effect so when a user pinches and zooms, it looks like they anchored their fingers on the plane and can pinch zoom realistically. To do this, I need to calculate the the distance between their fingers into distance in 3D space (which I already can do), but then I need to map that 3D distance to a z value.

For example, if a 100 units wide square and shrunk to 50 units (50%), how much further back would the camera need to move to make that 100 unit square shrink by half?

So to put it simply, If I have the distance in 3D space, how do I calculate the distance of the camera needed to shrink that 3D space by a certain amount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

So, I tried it myself and came up with this formula:

[image]

So let's say you are 1 unit away from the object.
When you want to shrink it to 50% (zoomfactor) the new distance equals 2 units => 1 / 0.5 = 2. The camera must be twice as far away.

---

Moving the camera closer to the plane for zooming only works with a *perspective* projection. The absolute distance depends on the angle of view. Usually you zoom by reducing the angle of view and not moving the camera at all.

If you are using an *orthographic* projection you can simply adjust the field of view / scale the projection matrix.

Comment: Thank you, using angle of view rather than zooming seems to be working a lot smoother now!

Comment: Actually that is exactly what zooming is. Imagine the zoom function of a real camera: you don't have to move closer, just press a button and the camera adjusts the lense. Glad I could help!